# Why can not get annotation from beanClass?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop

```
@Transactional
@Component
@EntranceLog
public class TransferServiceImpl implements TransferService {

    xxxx

}
```

I hava a class with `Transactional` annotation and `Component` annotation. `EntranceLog` is my customize annotation to print log by aop.

```
public class LogProxyCreator extends AbstractAutoProxyCreator implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final LogInterceptor LOG = new LogInterceptor();

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogProxyCreator.class);

    @Override
    protected Object[] getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(Class<?> beanClass, String s, TargetSource targetSource) throws BeansException {
        Annotation anno = null;

        for (Annotation annotationTemp : beanClass.getAnnotations()) {
            Log temp = annotationTemp.annotationType().getAnnotation(EntranceLog.class);
            if (temp != null) {
                anno = temp;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (anno == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Object[] additional =  new Object[]{LOG};

        log.error(beanClass.getName() + " has register the fc log.");

        return additional;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        LOG.setContext(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

When my app is starting, the bean transferServiceImpl start, but `beanClass.getAnnotations()` can not get any annotation. Why?

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Log(logName = "entrance")
public @interface EntranceLog {
    @AliasFor(
        annotation = Log.class,
        attribute = "subLogName"
    )
    String logName() default "";

    @AliasFor(
        annotation = Log.class,
        attribute = "openInfoLog"
    )
    boolean openInfoLog() default false;
}
```

This is my annotation.

Comment: What is the definition of the annotation? Is it even persisted through the compilation?

Comment: @vegaasen Yes, it can persist through the compilation. The definition of annotation is simple. My purpose is to proxy the bean with `EntranceLog` annotation, but when app is starting, I can't get any annotation from the bean.

Comment: I suggest you add the annotation's code, maybe something in its definition stop it from persisting

Comment: @niceman I add my annotation's code.

Comment: @vegaasen I add my annotation's code.

Comment: And I remove `Transactional ` annotation, all things is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring `@Transactional`is already an AOP processed annotation, so adding your own will require some additional work. Let me explain how Spring AOP and `@Transactional` works.

Spring has two ways of doing AOP, if the class implements an interface it *can* use a standard JDK Proxy, if the class does not implement an interface it will create a new subclass by using CGLib to emit bytecode at runtime. Unless you are very careful you will almost always get a CGLib proxy with Spring AOP.

When Spring encounters a `@Transactional` (class or method level) it creates a new subclass using CGLib, you can think of this class as a decorator, which forwards all calls to your implementation class. Before and after (around Advice) it check the `@Transactional` annotation properties, and check Thread Local storage to see if a transaction already exist, if there is no transaction it creates one, and remembers it so it can commit it afterwards. If you set a breakoint inside a `Transactional` method and look at the callstack you will see the call to your implementation came from the decorater class, and that there is no source code for it.

In your case the bean that is added to the Application Context, is not your `TransferServiceImpl`bean, but the CGLib proxy created by Spring when it found the `@Transactional` annotation on your class, it will be named something like `TransferServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$<hexstring>` - This class does not have the `@EntranceLog` annotation, which is why your own aspect is not working.

I have never encountered this problem myself, as I try to avoid AOP in general, or at always on classes that are already being CGLib proxied by Spring. Unless you want to dig deep into the Spring source, or find someone on the Spring dev team to help you with this, I suggest that you create another layer of indirection, so you don't need to handle two aspects in the same class.

Comment: Indeed, I should add another layer to handler my transaction, shouldn't add `Transactional` in my exposed service. That's great answer for me, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may be unwilling or unable to alter their code structure in order to avoid this issue, the following can probably help:

As Klaus mentioned, Spring creates a decorator class when it encounters a class tagged with `@Transactional`. However, because this new class is just that--a decorator--you should be able to call `getSuperclass()` on `beanClass` to give you the actual class Spring is decorating, like so:

`beanClass.getSuperclass().getAnnotations()`

If you're using your own Annotation, ensure it also persists through runtime by annotating the Annotation class with:

`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`